# How to extract / convert gff3 CDS sequences to multifasta

Tags: fasta, software-recommendation, format-conversion, gff3

I would like to extract all the CDS from a batch of genomes. I have found a perl script from [BioStars](https://www.biostars.org/p/46281/) but this does not seem to work for me. I would preferably like to have a script/ method which will use the locus tag as a header.

**Example**

My gff files are from prokka output

```
ATCC0000    Prodigal:2.6    CDS 243 434 .   +   0   ID=FKKLIMLP_00001;Parent=FKKLIMLP_00001_gene;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6;locus_tag=FKKLIMLP_00001;product=hypothetical protein
ATCC0000    prokka  gene    243 434 .   +   .   ID=FKKLIMLP_00001_gene;locus_tag=FKKLIMLP_00001
ATCC0000    Prodigal:2.6    CDS 1727    2131    .   -   0   ID=FKKLIMLP_00002;Parent=FKKLIMLP_00002_gene;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6;locus_tag=FKKLIMLP_00002;product=hypothetical protein
```

Comment: If you are comfortable with python/biopython you can look into this GFF parser: https://github.com/chapmanb/bcbb/tree/master/gff

Comment: I think gffread is the best choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like `bedtools getfasta`.  My typical option set is `bedtools getfasta -fi <reference> -bed <gff_file> -name -s`.  Be aware of the `-s` to make sure you are pulling the correct strand.  I like bedtools because it is a versatile tool overall for handling bed, gff and vcf file manipulations.

```
# bedtools getfasta

Tool:    bedtools getfasta (aka fastaFromBed)
Version: v2.26.0
Summary: Extract DNA sequences from a fasta file based on feature coordinates.

Usage:   bedtools getfasta [OPTIONS] -fi <fasta> -bed <bed/gff/vcf>

Options: 
    -fi Input FASTA file
    -bed    BED/GFF/VCF file of ranges to extract from -fi
    -name   Use the name field for the FASTA header
    -split  given BED12 fmt., extract and concatenate the sequencesfrom the BED "blocks" (e.g., exons)
    -tab    Write output in TAB delimited format.
        - Default is FASTA format.

    -s  Force strandedness. If the feature occupies the antisense,
        strand, the sequence will be reverse complemented.
        - By default, strand information is ignored.

    -fullHeader Use full fasta header.
        - By default, only the word before the first space or tab is used.
```

Answer (score 4):

The [gffread utility](http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/stringtie/gff.shtml#gffread) in Cufflinks package might be interesting for you. To generate a multi-fasta file with nucleotide sequences from your GFF file, then you can try:

```
gffread -w output_transcripts.fasta -g reference_genome.fa input_transcripts.gff
```

Answer (score 3):

Using python and [this GFF parser](https://github.com/chapmanb/bcbb/tree/master/gff) that mimics [Biopython's SeqIO parsers](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO):

```
from BCBio import GFF

# Read the gff
for seq in GFF.parse('my_file.gff'):
    # only focus on the CDSs
    for feat in filter(lambda x: x.type == 'CDS',
                       seq.features):
        # extract the locus tag
        locus_tag = feat.qualifiers.get('locus_tag',
                                        ['unspecified'])[0]
        # extract the sequence
        dna_seq = seq = str(feat.extract(seq).seq)
        # simply print the sequence in fasta format
        print('>%s\n%s' % (locus_tag, dna_seq))
```

Comment: AFAIK GFF3 is a version of GFF, and the page that advertises the BCBio parser indicates that it is compatible in reading/writing GFF3: http://biopython.org/wiki/GFF_Parsing

Answer (score 2):

The `xtractore` program from the [AEGeAn Toolkit](http://brendelgroup.github.io/AEGeAn/) was designed for this type of use case. Just set `--type=CDS`.

```
$ xtractore -h

xtractore: extract sequences corresponding to annotated features from the
           given sequence file

Usage: xtractore [options] features.gff3 sequences.fasta
  Options:
    -d|--debug            print debugging output
    -h|--help             print this help message and exit
    -i|--idfile: FILE     file containing a list of feature IDs (1 per line
                          with no spaces); if provided, only features with
                          IDs in this file will be extracted
    -o|--outfile: FILE    file to which output sequences will be written;
                          default is terminal (stdout)
    -t|--type: STRING     feature type to extract; can be used multiple
                          times to extract features of multiple types
    -v|--version          print version number and exit
    -V|--verbose          print verbose warning and error messages
    -w|--width: INT       width of each line of sequence in the Fasta
                          output; default is 80; set to 0 for no
                          formatting
```

It looks like you're processing prokaryotic genomes, but this program works also on eukaryotic genomes where CDSs often have introns interspersed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `agat_sp_extract_sequences.pl` from [AGAT](https://github.com/NBISweden/AGAT).
See here for all option: https://agat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/agat_sp_extract_sequences.html.

Below example of use:

[image]